# How to configure Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2, syntax-highlighting

So I want my Sublime Text 2 to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgc82.png). To that end, I installed the corresponding theme and font (DejaVuSansMono). But no matter what I do, a/ the font doesn't change to what I want it to change to; b/ the syntax highlighting is completely different from the screenshot.

WHat the hell is going on? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the font issue, add the following in your user settings:

```
"font_face": "DejaVu Sans Mono"
```

For the syntax highlight you should add:

```
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme"
```

Comment: Well, I know that, and did do it (http://i.imgur.com/SBIIbBr.png), but here is the result: http://i.imgur.com/XmXFmoP.png. As you can see, neither the syntax highlighting nor the font matches the screenshot I posted in the first post.

Comment: You have an error, is `DejaVu Sans Mono` instead of `Deja Vu Sans Mono`. Careful with the space.

Comment: Thanks. What about the syntax highlighting?

Comment: The color scheme seems to be `"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme"`.